# concurrent futures threadpoolexecutor repeating list items

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multithreading

I'm new to multi-threading in Python, and trying to manage a script that calls thousands of APIs. I've read a number of answers and articles and got to this:

```
import requests
import json
import time
import sys
import concurrent.futures
import threading


thread_local = threading.local()
pet_data = []


def get_session():
    if not hasattr(thread_local, "session"):
        thread_local.session = requests.Session()
    return thread_local.session


def scrape(url):
    session = get_session()
    with session.get(url) as response:
        info = response.text
        pet_data.append(json.loads(info))


def run_scrapes(sites):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=12) as executor:
        executor.map(scrape, sites)
        executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

sites is a list of the urls to call (it's a paginated API, so it's a simple list of 'api.endpoint&page='+str(i) URLs).

It works fine, but the issue I'm having is that it repeats calls, many times (based on debugging through logs, 6 of each URL gets called, even though there's only 1 of each in the list).

Is there something off in the code I've piece-mailed from articles/answers? I admit to not fully understanding the get_session function, which I suppose could be the issue.

Comment: Hello Brian, I added another suggestion as an Addendum to my answer.

Comment: Your main solution worked perfectly! But I'm going to learn more about async and try that out as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fundamental flaw in how you use the thread's local data object. This object is thread-local (hence the name) and needs to be fetched per-thread. Fetching it from the main thread like you do, and then reusing it in `get_session()`, will share the same Session object between threads. You need to always fetch it in the thread:

```
def get_session():
    thread_local = threading.local()
    if not hasattr(thread_local, "session"):
        thread_local.session = requests.Session()
    return thread_local.session
```

It is unclear to me if Session objects are thread-safe (there is conflicting information out there). This might be the cause of your problem.

You are also using the paradigm wrongly in collecting the results. What you should do is return the respective data from `scrape()`. Then collect it through the `map()` call:

```
pet_data = list(executor.map(scrape, sites))
```

This part is not critical though.

**Addendum**

Your main issue however, is that you do not use the right tool for the job. For asynchronous I/O like HTTP requests, you should use Python's asyncio capabilities, e.g. by using `httpx`: https://www.python-httpx.org/async/

This way all requests can run concurrently, even if you start them from a single thread. Multithreading in many cases does not help much with Python due to the GIL.

Comment: I'd love to see a reference for "Python data structures are not thread-safe", because I think that's not the case at all, as as you know, the GIL prevents multiple threads from running Python code concurrently.

Comment: You are right, it is the Session object that is not thread-safe. I revised my answer.